# Why '0' does not equal null

Tags: php, null, comparison

From what I've learned in mathematics:

> whenever A = B and B = C, then also A = C

So if `null == false and false == '0', then null == '0'`

Let's try this in PHP

```
<?php

echo (false == null); // true
echo (false == '0'); // true
echo (null == '0'); // false

?>
```

Apparently my shiny mathematical base doesn't fit in this context and I don't know why?

**Edit**

I need more clarification on what is happening internally? does PHP convert both sides to boolean ? or is it nothing to something comparison?

Comment: Because null is [nothing](https://techterms.com/definition/null)

Comment: and 0 is "something"

Comment: In the words of a great CS teacher, don’t trust intuition, trust the docs. Natural language doesn’t care about intuition, neither do artificial languages ;) what kind of answer would you like to this question?

Comment: @funk-forty-niner so how can "nothing" equal 0 which is something? :D

Comment: because `(null == '0')` the zero here in quotes is considered a string and is not equal to nothing; so if you were to change that to `(null == 0)` you will get TRUE

Comment: _"From what I've learned in mathematics"_ - Programming is not mathematics. Well, not exactly. It's not your mathematical base. You should start with the type theory if you wish to know more.

Comment: @AlexKarshin Googled it, and first sentence in Wikipedia is "In mathematics" :D

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yes, but try this 0 == "0" (true). That's because PHP will compare depending on context situation. If you want to compare strictly, is 0 === "0" (false)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 'real' (strict) equivalence in PHP is `===` . If you use it you do enjoy the transitivity property you've mentioned.

But `==` isn't an exact equivalence in PHP. It employs converting operands to a common type first. As we can see, using `false` as the first operand causes the second one to be reduced toward a Boolean value. If, however, you compare a reference to a string, no such reduction happens that's why the values are treated to be different. Of course such an approach violates the transitivity property. But, again, `===` is a 'real' equality sign rather than `==`.

Comment: "If, however, you compare a reference to string, no such reduction happens"  But ´ echo (null == '')´ equals 1 ?

Comment: I meant reducing '0' to a Boolean type. But we may have a hierarchy of possible reductions. They are generally referred to as type conversion but it may be also be empty vs. non empty and set vs. isn't set. Whatever is the most specific common trait of two types.

Comment: One may find the exact explanation of such a process in PHP docs. This Q is 'Why..?' and it's interesting as such. I don't recommend anybody to spell '==' operator magic unless you really want some implicit cast. It makes a code confusing and error prone. I would recommend to use '===' primarily.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of it as this, Null just means the value is "undefined". But "0" defines the variable to be an integer, 0 is a value! Null is not declared to be anything. Therefore it is false.

so something which is defined ("0") cannot equal to something that is undefined ("Null").

Edit - note that some languages do set null to be a designated value, either 0 if as an integer, false as a bool, etc. But others don't default it to be anything. PHP might not default null as an integer.

Comment: About your note; one such as mysql doesn't consider NULL as being empty also, so that's kind of a "catch 22" when using php to check if something is null.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is about this: PHP (like other languages) can compare variables with flexible mode or strict mode.

If you try this... (note the TRIPLE ===)

```
echo (false === null); // result = false
echo (false === '0'); // result = false
echo (null === '0'); // result = false
```

That means comparison in strict mode, which means compare value and type. You did compare in flexible, which is not very trustable since this may unpredictable results, unless you don't need to get strict.
A typical flexible comparison is i.e.

```
$myvar = null;
if($myvar == false)  ....
```

Which is the same as...

```
if(!$myvar) ...
```

So, if you really want to trust in type comparison, use triple equal ===

Anyway, I would bet that null=='0' is true, but it seems like is false.